# Unable to download build 0x project

Tags: 0x

I'm trying to follow the instructions on [0x API project](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api), but I see the following message when trying to install dependencies:

```
node-pre-gyp http GET https://0x-neon-router.s3.amazonaws.com/0.3.1/node-v93-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 403 Forbidden on https://0x-neon-router.s3.amazonaws.com/0.3.1/node-v93-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
```

Any idea if this is expected?

Comment: Please contact 0x team for 0x bugs and issues. You are on a wrong forum.

Comment: they're directing all support issues here.

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently have ARM builds for MacOS. Try running in rosetta mode or the Dockerfile.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response. Let me try that